# Can I call a namespaced function with jquery contentWindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am working with some legacy code and I'm looking for a safe way to handle the following scenario:

I have an iframe showing a product selection page. I need to pass this iframe the name of a callback function with a query string.

In the iframe I get the callback name from the query string and execute it like so:

```
$("iframe#content:first", window.top.document)[0].contentWindow[callbackName]();
```

But this only works if the callback is a globally exposed function. That's lame. 
This callback should live in a nested object.

Is there any way I can specify a callback like :

```
'myNamespace.nestedNamespace.myCallbackFunction'
```

and execute it off of the contentWindow object ?

Comment: I am unable to test right now, but what about `...[0].contentWindow.myNamespace.nestedNamespace.myCallbackFunction();`

Comment: The namespaces and the depth is unknown until the page is called. I want other developer to hand this page a callback to execute. 
This would work if I knew exactly which function I want to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, if I understand correctly, something like the following should do the trick:

```
// Your callback "path".
var callbackPath = 'myNamespace.nestedNamespace.myCallbackFunction';
if (callbackPath != '') {
    // We will need to walk our way to the actual callback.
    var parts = callbackPath.split('.');
    var callback = $("iframe#content:first", window.top.document)[0].contentWindow;

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
        callback = callback[ parts[i] ];

        // Was unable to find callback, bail!
        if (!callback)
            break;
    }

    if (typeof callback === 'function')
        callback();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! glad that I could help :)